# How do i seamlessly join these seperate objects?

Tags: modeling, vertices

Is there a way I can attatch the hand to the wrist and match the shapes together?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

let me show you one way of doing this.

This setup should mimic your setup.

[image]

- First we have to Join both of the Objects into one single
- Select both and press "ctrl + J"

Now you have one single object

- Open the new combined object in Edit mode
- Delete the faces that are in-between the merge on both sides!

[image]

Now normally you should be able to select the edges of your two objects and type the command "Bridge edge loops"

[image]
[image]

Comment: Actually you don't even need to delete the faces when you bridge

Comment: Oh i didn't know that thanks!